# Azure Storage Explorer : Unable to retrieve child resources

Tags: azure, azure-storage-explorer

Getting error ONLY while accessing Blob storage.

No issues in Queues, File Share or table.
Any idea ?

```
Unable to retrieve child resources.

Details:
["FetchError:request to https://fssaicessunsetsbxv1sa.blob.core.windows.net/?include=metadata&comp=list failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate"]
```

Comment: Take a look at this link, it might help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-troubleshooting?tabs=Windows%2C1804#error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain-and-similar-errors

Comment: tried that .. no luck :(

Comment: I found this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53393.azure-storage-explorer-troubleshooting-unable-to-retrieve-child-resources-or-the-request-action-could-not-be-completed.aspx which doesn't really narrow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have set any RBAC policies?
If you are connected to Azure through a proxy, verify that your proxy settings are correct. If you were granted access to a resource from the owner of the subscription or account, verify that you have read or list permissions for that resource.

If possible can you try to un-install and reinstall the [latest version](https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/releases) and check for the status of the issue.

Azure Storage Explorer Troubleshooting: ["unable to retrieve child resources” or “The request action could not be completed”.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53393.azure-storage-explorer-troubleshooting-unable-to-retrieve-child-resources-or-the-request-action-could-not-be-completed.aspx)

If the issue still persist after trying above mentioned steps, I would like to work closer on this issue. Let me know the status

Answer (score 4):

Error : **Self-Signed Certificate in Certificate Chain ,Unable to retrieve child resources.**

Issue for me: I am attached with office proxy server. But Azure Storage Explorer is not using that proxy.

Solution:

> Azure Storage Explorer -> Edit -> Configure Proxy,
> **Source = No proxy** "Changed to"     **Use System proxy(preview)**

After making these changes; I am able access the resources.

Moreover, Verify the permissions do you have on the connection string?

To generate your connection string either through the Azure Portal or some apps. When you generate the connection string, you need to give "Allowed permissions". Beside Read/Write you also need the List permission so Storage Explorer can list the blobs. Here is a screenshot in Azure portal to check/uncheck the permissions:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Warning: For the noobs !

if you got luck you can also fix it by closing and re-opening the visual studio.

Reason: Authorization is tightly coupled with azure

Motivation: To err is Human ! Even Soft. DEV working at Microsoft are Human.